# when didRangeBeacons,ExitRegion and EnterRegion methods are calling app in background or killed for local notifications in ios?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

`didRangeBeacons`,`didExitRegion` and `didEnterRegion` methods are calling when app in background or not in background.

Then I am getting local notification after 30 minutes or some times like after 1 hours for iOS. When those methods are listening or calling I have no idea?

Comment: I attempted to edit this question to clarify what you mean, but I'm afraid I can't figure out exactly what you are asking. Could you edit to ask a precise and clear question?

Comment: You should include some of your code. Also note that beacons need always location access, so they will work in foreground and background